# Circle-Circle intersection coordinate system

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, vector-analysis, polar-coordinates

Consider two points in the 2D Euclidean plane, the origin $0$ and $x$. One can define a co-ordinate system such that for any point $y$ in the plane, $y$ is parametrized by its distance from $0$, call it $r$, and its distance from $x$, call it $L$, and a binary choice, say $+$ or $-$. How does one transform this co-ordinate system with the Cartesian coordinate system, and what is the integrating factor (i.e. area element)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-center_bipolar_coordinates

This is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's great, thanks! Is there anything like that for higher dimensions? (Again parametrized by the distance to two centers, with the other parameter being an element $\xi \in S^{d-2} $ ?

Comment: @Robert: why not? You've pretty much defined it yourself.

Comment: True, but I'd like to know if the volume element (a.k.a. integrating factor) is worked out anywhere of arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: I suppose you'd want $n$ distances from $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to pin down location of a point to two possible points.

Comment: "That's great, thanks! Is there anything like that for higher dimensions?" - look up bispherical and toroidal coordinates.